# amazon aws ec2 free tier

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud-hosting

I am just starting out the AWS free tier and i have the following questions :

The "15 GB of out bandwidth out aggregated across all AWS services". Is this on a per month basis ?

I have a windows AMI running. Will RDP/remoting into the EC2 server from my home computer count against the OUT bandwidth ?

Where can i go look at the consolidated bandwidth usage ?  I went through this link https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=278407, but couldnt find the option "AWS Data Transfer" section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's [per month](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/).  RDP usage will use both in and out bandwidth, since you send input (keyboard, mouse, etc.), and it sends (mainly) screen changes.

Comment: thank you. Could you also point me to where i can find the aggregated bandwidth used on the account?

Answer (score 3):

The aggregated bandwidth and usage reports can be viewed from the link

https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/account?ie=UTF8&action=activity-summary

This is according to how its specified in the aws forum link. I am attaching a screenshot to make it more clear. Expand the green highlighted portion as shown in the image to get bandwidth usage details.

[image]